# Are form requests automatically encrypted, on an SSL/HTTPS enabled server?

Tags: html, vue.js, security, ssl, https

I want to create a form in `vue 3` and send it via `POST` through an `ajax` request to my `Laravel` backend. The server I am working on has `SSL` and `HTTPS` enabled.

Will the `content` of the requests be encrypted or do I have to enable `HTTPS` for each form manually in `Javascript`?

Comment: Is the form action URL a relative URL?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes

Comment: If the server has SSL/HTTPS enabled doesn't matter if you don't use it. So is the ajax request using an HTTPS URL or not, that is the question here?